# EJB is not binding and giving InvalidName error in websphere 8.5.12

Tags: binding, ejb, idl

EJB binding issue for few EJBs (which are meant for remote access only) in websphere 8.5.12. All other ejbs started except few with the InvalidName error. It's a legacy application, which we are trying to port from websphere 6 to websphere 8.5.12

Tried with few jndi options but the error is same.
The actual supposed to be jndi name ="com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome"

```
[1/28/19 0:04:13:365 EST] 00000052 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: ofr_ConsolidationRegionMgr.jar
[1/28/19 0:04:13:369 EST] 00000052 WASNameSpaceB I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome interface of the com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr enterprise bean in the ofr_ConsolidationRegionMgr.jar module of the ofr application.  The binding location is: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome
[1/28/19 0:04:13:369 EST] 00000052 AbstractEJBRu I   CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome interface of the com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr enterprise bean in the ofr_ConsolidationRegionMgr.jar module of the ofr application.  The binding location is: java:global/ofr/ofr_ConsolidationRegionMgr/com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome
[1/28/19 0:04:13:388 EST] 00000052 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/hd/tp/talon_db2/talon_db2_instance/logs/ffdc/ofrserver_506a20db_19.01.28_00.04.13.3737642906525301202256.txt com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.<init> 5347
[1/28/19 0:04:13:388 EST] 00000052 SharedNameSpa E   WSVR0046E: Unable to bind, com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome. Original exception : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
[1/28/19 0:04:13:389 EST] 00000052 SharedNameSpa E   WSVR0046E: Unable to bind, com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome. Original exception : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
[1/28/19 0:04:13:396 EST] 00000052 SharedEJBRunt E   WSVR0040E: addEjbModule failed for ofr_ConsolidationRegionMgr.jar
javax.naming.InvalidNameException: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome. Original exception : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.processException(CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.java:488)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.rebindPostProcess(CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.java:1413)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.executeBatchedOperations(CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.java:1652)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.javaCNBatchContextImpl.executeBatchedOperations(javaCNBatchContextImpl.java:278)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.executeBatchedOperation(WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.java:235)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.end(WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.java:1233)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:762)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:338)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3588)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)

[1/28/19 0:04:13:399 EST] 00000052 DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, ofr_ConsolidationRegionMgr.jar, of application, ofr.ear/deployments/ofr, failed to start
[1/28/19 0:04:13:402 EST] 00000052 ApplicationMg E   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, ofr
[1/28/19 0:04:13:402 EST] 00000052 ApplicationM
```

---

Additional exception trace:
[1/28/19 0:04:14:506 EST] 00000001 ContainerHelp E   WSVR0501E: Error creating component com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@f0ad7395
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome. Original exception : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1303)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:275)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:540)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:229)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:702)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:406)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:169)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome. Original exception : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl.join(WsComponentImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1295)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome. Original exception : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:768)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.startModule(SharedEJBRuntimeImpl.java:338)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3588)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr!com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome. Original exception : org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.InvalidName: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/InvalidName:1.0
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.processException(CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.java:488)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.rebindPostProcess(CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.java:1413)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.executeBatchedOperations(CommonBatchModeCNContextImpl.java:1652)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jbatch.javaCNBatchContextImpl.executeBatchedOperations(javaCNBatchContextImpl.java:278)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.executeBatchedOperation(WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.java:235)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.end(WASNameSpaceBinderImpl.java:1233)
        at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.startModule(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:762)
        ... 19 more

Snippets from ejb-jar.xml

```
 <enterprise-beans>
                <session id="ConsolidationRegionMgr">
                        <ejb-name>com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr</ejb-name>
                        <home>com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome</home>
                        <remote>com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr</remote>
                        <ejb-class>com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrBean</ejb-class>
                        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
                        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
                </session>
        </enterprise-beans>
```

---

Snippets from ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd="commonbnd.xmi" xmlns:com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.ejbbnd="ejbbnd.xmi" xmlns:org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb="ejb.xmi" xmi:id="ejb-jar_ID_Bnd">
  <defaultDatasource xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1">
    <defaultAuth xmi:type="com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.commonbnd:BasicAuthData" xmi:id="BasicAuthData_1"/>
  </defaultDatasource>
  <ejbJar href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ejb-jar_ID"/>
  <ejbBindings xmi:id="com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgr_bnd" jndiName="com.logistics.optifreight.optimizationmgmt.consolidation.consolidationregion.ejb.consolidationregionmgr.ConsolidationRegionMgrHome">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb:Session" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ConsolidationRegionMgr"/>
  </ejbBindings>
</com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding>
~
```

Comment: section in ejb-jar.xml

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly your issue is?

Comment: Out of the 250+ EJBs from this EAR only about 3 EJBs are not starting during server startup with this binding exception. During server startup all EJBs except these three which are more relevant for remote calls are not coming up with this InvalidName exception in websphere 8.5.12. Please note they are working perfectly fine in all environments including in production for the past many years in websphere 6.0 and when we are trying redeploy and migrate the ear from websphere 6 to websphere 8.5.12 we are getting this binding exceptions during server start up and these EJBs are not starting.

Comment: any clues? anybody? not able to figure out, what exactly it's complaining as 'InvalidName'

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved: It turned out the jndi name and ejb-name, we were using is too big of a name and its causing issue within the global-binding. After trying so many options, finally when we suspected this and gave a smaller name, those EJBs got binded.